# check repeated data in input while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input

```
<input required type="text" id="Editbox1"name="EditboxD" value="00" maxlength="2">
```

I need to check if the user wrote a repeated value like 00 or 22 while he is typing and showing alert !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the shorthand most efficient way

```
var last;
document.getElementById('Editbox1').addEventListener('keypress',(e)=>last = (last === undefined) ? e.keyCode : (e.keyCode === last) ? alert('repeated data') : e.keyCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for 2 repeating characters then you could do this:

```
var lastKey = '';

$('#Editbox1').on('keyup', function(e) {
  //You probably don't want to check to see if they entered backspace twice. 
  //You could also check for other keys like this for example the ENTER key or the TAB key
  //It might even make more sense to use keyCode ranges depending on your use
  if (e.keyCode === 8 ) {
    return;
  }

  //if the current key and last key were the same
  if (lastKey === String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)) {
    alert();
  //otherwise store the current key into the lastKey var to be check on the next keypress
  } else {
    lastKey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  }
});
```